# Steam web api nodejs wrapper callbacks?

Tags: node.js, express

Im trying to write a small web api to fetch data from Steam(gaming platform) with nodejs and expressjs.

Im using this guys nodejs wrapper: https://github.com/brainss/steamAPI

The problem is, that this guy is using console.log as a callback... Im getting the data just fine, in my node server console.

I need it return the data as a json string using expressJs's res.json.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an anonymous function and go from there:

```
steam.getNewsForApp({
    appid: 550,
    count: 10,
    maxlength: 300
}, function(data) {
    res.send(data);
});
```

Comment: I kid you not, i just found it! So obvious ofc!

Thanks alot man! 

This is the answer, ill accept it in 4 minutes :)